# How to use an existing sqlite database in html5

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have created an sqlite database file using sqlite browser.I have a file "sample.sqlite", now i wanted to know how to import this file in javascript and use the data in the sqlite file.I have been using this below mentioned script

```
var db;

try {
    if (window.openDatabase) {
        db = openDatabase("sample.sqlite", "1.0", "HTML5 Database API example", 200000);
        if (!db)
            alert("Error Failed to open the database, check version");
    } else
        alert("Error Not supported? Not gonna happen");
} catch(err) {}
```

By using this code i am not able to get the data from sqlite file.Please suggest me how to proceed.i have seen some sites where steps have been mentioned to create table,insert data by writing code in java script itself.But i don't know to do it that way i want to import the existing sqlite file.

Comment: Be more specific than `i am not able to get the data`.

Comment: I also am stuck on this concept of 'loading' an existing Sqlite database (say it's called employees.db) into the browser. Html pages are served from the webserver to the browser. Can I not also use Javascript to load a *.db file from the web server into the browser? Any examples I have seen start with an empty canvas...using Javascript (so it's all client-side work). They create an in-browser database, create tables and INSERT data....Is this the only way? Am I missing something ? I would like to pull this employees.db file from a webserver using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Web apps are not allowed to access arbitrary files on the computer.

You could download some data from the same server where your JavaScript code comes from, but it would be easier and faster to embed the SQL commands to create your database in your code.
(Use the `.dump` command of the `sqlite3` command-line tool to get these SQL commands.)

Comment: `Web apps are not allowed to access arbitrary files on the computer.` Not _entirely_ true. There is (limited) support for that, via [the File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-FileAPI-20121025/). Still, +1!

Answer (score 0):

for Safari browser:

create dummy database in your HTML5.

after that copy database file name from mentioned location.

**\Application Data\Apple Computer\Safari\Databases{your domain name}{database File name}**

replace your database file name from newer one. and paste into the above mentioned location.

open your HTML5 page i hope it's work's good.

Comment: Not really a solution I would give an end user.