# How to open existing database in websql

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I want to connect to *sqlite* existing database in `Javascript` via `WebSql`.
I follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626918/how-to-open-an-existing-websql-database) and my problem not resolved.

I did following :

1. copy my sqlite database beside of the `"index.html"`
2. in the `"index.html"`, I add below code :

   ```
   db = openDatabase('filename.sqlite', '', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
   ```

When I open `"index.html"`, on chrome developer tools and "Resources" tab, an **empty** database created with a `"filename.sqlite"` name. In fact, a new database created!

Any suggestion?

Comment: It might be unrelated to your question, but what version of chrome are you running on?

Comment: My chrome version is 43

Comment: Try http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/3903201/Using-the-Web-SQL-Database-API-in-HTML-5.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an existing sqlite database in html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613487/how-to-use-an-existing-sqlite-database-in-html5)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open database file from javascript. This doesn't work. Chrome just creates a new DB with name: `filename.sqlite` if it doesn't exits. What you need to edit .sqlite database is `sqlite3`